# Distinct singular values of a matrix perturbed with a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it always possible to perturb a matrix using a symmetric matrix such that its singular values become distinct?

Formally:

Let $A$ be an arbitrary (finite dimensional) complex square matrix. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Is there a complex symmetric (not Hermitean!) matrix $S$ such that $\lVert S\rVert\leq\varepsilon$ and $A+S$ has only distinct singular values?

**Note:** I don't care which matrix norm is used since we are in the finite dimensional case, and therefore all matrix norms are equivalent.

**Note:** I only ask about existence, I do not need a constructive way of finding $S$.

Comment: Interesting question. Did you have a look in the books of [Saad](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/books.html)? These are the first books I use, when it comes to numerical LA problems.

Comment: @PhilippSiehr No, I don't have or know them. But my question is not about numerical LA problems, I think. It's not about numerical stability under perturbations, for example, but rather about the density of one set inside another. E.g., if we drop the word "symmetric", the question is equivalent to asking "is the set of matrices with distinct singular values dense". (To which the answer is, by the way, yes.)

Comment: I think the answer to this question is also affirmative by topology and measure theory, since the set of matrices with non-distinct singular values is a rather thin closed set, while the symmetric matrices provide a rather large set of perturbations. Anyway, I am performing the requested migration towards MO.